# Update SharePoint item using Microsoft Flow?

Tags: file-upload, list-item, microsoft-flow

there are a few actions related to SharePoint available in [Microsoft Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com),
 e.g. "SharePoint - When a file is created" or "SharePoint - Update Item".
I am missing a way to connect these actions, though -
so is there a way to use Microsoft Flow to update the SharePoint ListItem of a file after that file has been created in a SharePoint document library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

MS Flow doesnt seem to allow you accomplish this at the moment - I came across this scenario as well.

You may be able to do it if you set up your flow using the Logic Apps in Azure

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/logic-apps/

You will need an azure subscription to create an app

Answer (score 0):

Automation of updating SharePoint list items in Microsoft Power Automate (MS Flow) can be achieved in 3 ways:

1. HTTP request to SharePoint (REST API)
2. SharePoint Update Item action.
3. Update SharePoint List Item action from Plumsail Actions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to use Power Automate (Microsoft Flow) to update the SharePoint list item of a file after that file has been created in a SharePoint document library.

The first step is to use the **When a file is created (properties only)** trigger an configure the site address an library name. This will cause the flow to run each time a file is added to the document library.

The second step is to use the **Update file properties** action to update the list item associated with the file (i.e. the file metadata). In the screen capture below, I am setting the value of the Number column to the list item ID.

[image: Power Automate flow]